# Как правильно передавать и обрабатывать пароль?

Tags: android, веб-программирование, безопасность

Подскажите, правильной ли будет такая схема работы **при регистрации**:

- введенные пользователем данные (пароль не шифруется, передается как
  есть) пересылаются по HTTPS на сервер
- по прибытию на сервер данные сохраняются в БД (пароль предварительно
  перед заносом в БД хешируется)

И схема работы **при входе в аккаунт**:

- так же не зашифрованные данные передаются по HTTPS
- по прибытию на сервер они проверяются на валидность с теми которые, в
  БД
- если они не валидны то пользователю отсылается сигнал о том что
  данные введены неверно
- если они валидны то здесь у меня возникает второй вопрос: **что
  делать дальше?**

P.S. клиентом является Android приложение
P.P.S. Не забудьте про первый вопрос "правильным ли будет такая схема?"

Comment: А что, на ваш взгляд, в схеме не правильно? Что делать дальше? Сгенерите какой нить ключ отдайте его и требуйте его для идентификации.

Comment: Сгенерить токен всмысле?

Comment: Да, чтобы не передавать пароль при каждом коннекте, ну и сделать этот токен со сроком годности... можно еще добавить привязку ip и т.п.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отсылка пароля через HTTPS это стандартная практика, с оговоркой:

1. Надо озаботиться наличием клиентского сертификата на устройстве, который будет принят сервером
2. Сервер должен форсировать HTTPS соединение, если к нему клиент стучится через обычный HTTP

> если они валидны то здесь у меня возникает второй вопрос: что делать дальше?

1. Берем `login` через него находим на сервере соль `salt`
2. Вычисляем `hash(password+salt)`
3. Сравниваем с сохраненным на сервере значением хэша - если успешно пускаем внутрь, если нет то отражаем.

Comment: я бы уточнил самый первый пункт, чтобы было что гуглить, надо сделать ssl pining